# django inlines with abstract model give error

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following in Django models.py (models are stripped down to only necessary fields)

```
class Product(BaseProduct):
    price       = models.IntegerField()
    productfoto = models.ManyToManyField("ProductFoto", related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']

# Inherits Product class
class ConsumerProduct(Product):
    categorie= models.ForeignKey(Categorie)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ConsumerProducten"


class ProductFoto(models.Model):
    myimage= FileBrowseField("Image", max_length=200, directory='producten')
```

and this in admins.py:

```
class ProductFotoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    extra = 1
    model = Product.productfoto.through

class ConsumerProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}
    inlines= [ProductFotoInline]
admin.site.register(ConsumerProduct, ConsumerProductAdmin)
```

Please take note of following:

- Product class is abstract
- ConsumerProduct inherits Product

I would say this should work, however I'm getting the following ImproperlyConfigured error when trying to add a new ConsumerProduct:

```
'model' is a required attribute of 'ConsumerProductAdmin.inlines[0]'.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `model = Product.productfoto.through`. Shouldn't this be `model = ProductFoto`?

Comment: unfortunately your approach gives `<class 'product.models.ProductFoto'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'product.models.ConsumerProduct'>`

I don't think this is the desired solution, since Product is an abstract class and ProductFoto should 'know' this and only add the refrence to the ConsumerProduct class somehow

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to make my Product class non-abstract. By removing the registration of this class with the admin (removing the line `admin.site.register(Product)`)
You will not see it in the backend, however in your database, it will be a bit more messy, because you will have both a `Product` and a `ConsumerProduct` table